# How to add login credentials to a make command?

Tags: makefile

Many times (not always) i need to enter my credentials when i run an app. I am using Appcelerator to build mobile apps and whenever  a coworker is also using the credentials i get booted out since it does not allow multiple users to be logged in at once. We have a Makefile that automates a lot of the tasks. When we do `make run` it cleans and runs our apps. However, we do need to enter our login credentials every time we are both developing. How do we make it to where if we are asked to enter our email and password it would automatically be entered?

Answer (score 0):

Auto-login for appcelerator ?

https://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/autologin-to-appcelerator-titanium/

http://johnjardin.ukuvuma.co.za/2013/07/15/appcelerator-tip-have-titanium-auto-login-on-startup/

I don't know if you are looking for that or not.

Comment: The thing is that the system boots me out once someone else uses that login. If no one else logs in then I will continue to be logged in.